# Webpack + node + express

Tags: css, node.js, express, webpack, compilation

I'm currently working on an express project to which i'm new. I have configured the web-pack file, but there seems to be an error for a css file. I'm finding it a little difficult to get past the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./public/stylesheets/fontawesome.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'file' in '/Users/xyz/Node-Projects/importer'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./public/stylesheets/fontawesome.css 7:332-383
 @ ./public/stylesheets/fontawesome.css
 @ ./public/index.js
```

My Web-pack config:

```
     {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader" , "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ["style-loader" ,"css-loader", "less-loader"]
      }
```

Index.js file:

```
import './stylesheets/fontawesome.css';
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: seems something wroing with line 7 in fontawesome.css. Can you provide the file content around that line?

Comment: hey loveky, there was a reference to a font file which was not present. Thanks :-)